# Max SubArray kadane Algorthim

Tags: c++, algorithm, kadanes-algorithm

```
void kadane(int A[], int N, int& bestStart, int& bestEnd, int& bestSum)
{

    int max_ending_here = 0;
    int max_so_far = 0;
    bestStart = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {

        max_ending_here += A[i];

        if (max_ending_here < 0)
        {
            max_ending_here = 0;
        }
        if (max_ending_here > max_so_far)
        {
            max_so_far = max_ending_here;
            bestEnd = i;
        }

    }
}
```

I want to update the best start index
If I have an array A={-1,-2,5,0,1}
Best start should be index 2 and best end index 4 I am getting the best end but i do not know how to update the best start
Max sub array here is = 6 (5+0+1)

Answer (score 0):

Keep potential best start index

```
bestStartCandidate = 0;

if (max_ending_here < 0)
    {
        max_ending_here = 0;
        bestStartCandidate = i + 1;       
    }
    if (max_ending_here > max_so_far)
    {
        max_so_far = max_ending_here;
        bestStart = bestStartCandidate;       
        bestEnd = i;
    }
```

Comment: Is not right actually I added so many if conditions until get the right answer thanks for help